# SQL Query in php comes blank

Tags: php, sql

i can print out the hash code fine,  then i check the value in the database and it matches fine. But, when i run the get_user_id - its not coming up with anything at all.  I am fairly new to programming,  so i am not sure what i am missing hope someone can point it out.

```
include("internals\config.php"); // DB info

$host       = DB_HOST;
$user       = DB_USER;
$password   = DB_PASS;
$dbname     = DB_NAME;
$prefix     = DB_TBL_PREFIX;

define('TBL_MAILBOX_CONVERSATION', $prefix.'mailbox_conversation');
define('TBL_MAILBOX_MESSAGE', $prefix.'mailbox_message');

$cxn = mysql_pconnect ($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db($dbname, $cxn);

$hash = ($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']!='' ? $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] : 'Guest');

function get_user_id() 
    {   
        $userid = NULL;

        if (!empty($hash)) 
        {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT `profile_id` FROM `skadate_profile_online` WHERE `hash` = '".$hash."' ");

            if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                $userid = $row[0];
            }
        }

        return $userid;
    }

$profile_id  = get_user_id();
print $profile_id;
```

Comment: Read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Hint: you might want to define a `function get_user_id_by_hash($hash){ ....}`

Comment: You posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/27340893/ - both questions seem the same, besides the difference of the additional Ajax.

Comment: Also you need a connection in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `$hash` to `get_user_id()`

Change

```
$profile_id  = get_user_id();
```

to

```
$profile_id  = get_user_id($hash);
```

Comment: not sure?  i used global $hash; and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

function get_user_id(); the $hash will always be empty as the value is never passed to the function.

Also, *Mysqli* -

fixed:

```
function get_user_id($funcHash) 
    {   
        $userid = NULL;

    if (!empty($funcHash)) 
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `profile_id` FROM `skadate_profile_online` WHERE `hash` = '".$funcHash."' ");

        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $userid = $row[0];
        }
    }

    return $userid;
}
```

so when you run the code you pass the $hash value to the function:

```
$profile_id  = get_user_id($hash);
```

EDITS:
point 1 - please consider using MySQLi instead of the standard MySQL as this is now full deprecated.

point 2- I deliberately changed the $hash variable in the function because this can easily get confusing, you have a $hash in the context of the function and another variable $hash in the context of the file, so the function one I renamed to $funcHash,

Comment: actually you helped but what i simply needed to do was add "global $hash;" -- but thanks for pointing out that it was = 0 and that was the problem.